# IActionFilter vs IResultFilter

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Please explain the difference between IActionFilter and IResultFilter. I understand that OnActionExecuting happens before an action method executes, and that OnActionExecuted happens after an action method executes, and further, what it means for an action method to execute. What I don't understand, in the context of IResultFilter, is what it means for an action result to execute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Action filters contain logic that is executed before and after a controller action executes. You can use an action filter, for instance, to modify the view data that a controller action returns.

Result filters (Or IResultFilters) contain logic that is executed before and after a view result is executed. For example, you might want to modify a view result right before the view is rendered to the browser.

Read [Understanding Action Filters.](https://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs)

To clarify what a ViewResult does lets look at the ViewResultBase execution:

```
      viewEngineResult = this.FindView(context);
      this.View = viewEngineResult.View;

      TextWriter output = context.HttpContext.Response.Output;
      this.View.Render(new ViewContext(context, this.View, this.ViewData, this.TempData, output), output);
```

You will see it first finds the view, then renders the view to the Response output stream.

Comment: But what specifically does it mean for a view result to be executed? Does it mean that View is called from a controller, which results in the View being executed, or what?

Comment: A ViewResult, renders a specifed view to the response stream

Comment: Thanks. I've been trying to think of a reason you might want to modify a view result right before rendering, but haven't come up with anything. Why wouldn't the view just do what it needs to do?

Comment: Sometimes a ViewResult might not be HTML, in which case why have a view at all? In the case of JSON, a download, etc.