# When to use ResultFilter in ASP.NET core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-1.1

According to this doc 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#result-filters the result filter will be executed after the action filter.

My question: what are the differences between implementing ActionFilter's OnActionExecuted and ResultFilter's OnResultExecuting given that I don't want to handle exception? It seems like the ActionFilter allows me to handle exception and skip the ExceptionFilter.

The example in the doc wasn't clear about how one should choose between Action filter or Result filter.

Could you please give an example when Result filter is more preferable than the Action filter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187076/iactionfilter-vs-iresultfilter

Comment: @PradeepKumar The SO thread your gave is for the old ASP.NET MVC. Is the behavior the same for ASP.NET core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Action filters** implement either the `IActionFilter` or `IAsyncActionFilter` interface, and their execution surrounds the execution of action methods. Action filters contain logic that is executed before and after a controller action executes.

**Result filters** implement either the `IResultFilter` or `IAsyncResultFilter` interface, and their execution surrounds the execution of action results. Result filters contain logic that is executed before and after a view result is executed.

> ActionFilter's OnActionExecuted and ResultFilter's OnResultExecuting

- ActionFilter's **OnActionExecuted**: It is called just after the action method is called. (For example - do some logic after the action executes view data modification)
- ResultFilter's **OnResultExecuting**: It is called just before the result is executed; it means before rendering the view. (For example - do some logic before view result modification.)

Comment: What prevents you from applying the logic in OnResultExecuting to OnActionExecuted?

Comment: Imagine, you have scenario like this- FirstAction > SecondAction > View. In this case, if you want to put some common logic after FirstAction is completed then that can be placed inside OnActionExecuted.